# VMware wants /dev/dsp, but it does not exist

Tags: sound, 64-bit, vmware

Running an MS-DOS virtual machine within VMware Workstation 9.01 requires the "virtual sound card" to be set to SB16.  However, when it is configured as SB16, it wants /dev/dsp.  This device does not exist.  All sound works fine in Ubuntu, and other virtual machines in Workstation 9 have fully functional sound.

Ubuntu 12.04, kernel is 3.2.0-37, platform is x64-SMP, oss-compat is already installed.  Launching vmware with padsp did not work either.  When launching the virtual machine, it still reports that /dev/dsp cannot be found.  Already tried setting the virtual sound card to Auto Detect and Alsa-Compatible Sound Card (these are the only two choices).  Result is the same.

From what I have been able to find so far, no one else is reporting this particular problem.  Suggestions for missing /dev/dsp have always involved pointing to a different device or installing oss-compat and/or alsa-oss.  Neither of these fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have had the same problem running a win 3.11 guest on a Gentoo host. Turned out modules for OSS was built and installed, but not loaded at boot. A simple `sudo modprobe snd-pcm-oss` made `/dev/dsp` accessible for vmware workstation 9.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to a bug/issue with Ubuntu 12.04.

If I read and understand the following post it has to do with missing modules and a workaround that will only work with higher versions of Ubuntu.

The post I refer to is this one: [oss-compat package does not create /dev/dsp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318396/oss-compat-package-does-not-create-dev-dsp)

This will not solve your problem but give you an explanation why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The device was present, but was only accessible by root or group audio (660). A simple chmod 666 /dev/dsp did the trick for me.
I don't know however, if this is realy a good thing to do.