# oss-compat package does not create /dev/dsp

Tags: 12.04, alsa, oss

As I understand it, the **oss-compat** package is supposed to enable ALSA's OSS compatibility layer to create /dev/dsp files for your sound devices for compatibility with older applications. It's description states:

```
The purpose of this package is for applications that only support OSS
to depend on it, hence preventing common "/dev/dsp not found" errors
that would confuse unexperienced users.
```

Yet after installing it, no /dev/dsp devices have been added to the system and older applications still have the same problems. Other [OSS emulation](http://www.alsa-project.org/~tiwai/OSS-Emulation.html) instructions also did not work.

I though it might have trouble as I have two sound devices (a sound card and tv/fm tuner), but physically removing one device and restarting made no difference.

I have also tried the **aoss** and **padsp** OSS wrapper applications but without success (works for applications not seeing /dev/mixer, but not those that require /dev/dsp).

Comment: Are the ALSA modules like `snd-pcm-oss` loaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the comments on a bug filed on [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/oss-compat/+bug/983707), it seems the **oss-compat** package works under the assumption that the ALSA OSS compatibility modules (`snd-pcm-oss`, `snd-seq-oss` and `snd-mixer-oss`) are already in your current installation. Unfortunately, it seems the Ubuntu kernel no longer includes these modules by default and it is necessary to recompile your kernel with a custom config to include them.

A simpler option (which is only available on newer Ubuntu versions) seems to be the **osspd** package that creates a daemon proxy for emulating OSS.

Comment: `osspd(8)` worked like a charm. You need to reboot your system beforehand though.